# how to keep submenu with images centered in bootstrap nav-pill

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Friends, I am facing responsive problem while arranging images in submenu centered. I have a container of width 1280px, for all screens. As you can see in fiddle I have categories as menu then when we click on categories it opens a menu with images. I want these menus to be centered on all screens and its border should cover the whole screen.

In simple words our categories should start exactly below of left side logo and all the images should be always centered on all screen. Now the submenu with images always shifts to left or right I want images in submenu to take container width always and fit in container for all desktop screens by leaving left and right margin, and whole submenu should cover entire screen please have a look at this code [demo](http://postimg.org/image/uwz75tml5/) for reference I am adding a screenshot please refer, and see if you can help me with this, thank you so much for giving your time.

This image shows what I am getting now [problem_img](http://postimg.org/image/uwz75tml5/)
This is what I want [exact_img](http://postimg.org/image/axil1ieu1/) this is although have some less space at right. but I need something like this, all content should be fit in container width and leaving same space at left and right and background black that covers entire screen size. I tried with margin-left but it fits only for the screen for which I set, please help me in making this menu responsive. Any help suggestions are appreciated. [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w7gmcb3/)
Thank you.

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/p7qrv3av/
```

Comment: `I have a container of width 1280px, for all screens` not many/any phones with that width - it will look broken

Comment: I want for desktop, so i have given container width as 1280px

Comment: Just as a note: in your jsfiddle, you put the CSS code into the JavaScript field instead of the CSS field

Comment: Oh sorry for that I will update thank you

Comment: Check if this helps you https://jsfiddle.net/p7qrv3av/2/

Comment: No @Tushar please check from 1280px to dragging screen for 1920px and more your code fits for only screen which you did, same as I did. Please check this by making a file and runnning in chrome and changing screeens width thank you for the try

Comment: To Start your categories  below the logo image. Make category div relative to the `.container` and remove `-66%` of `margin-left`. It will cause the main issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsdev/p7qrv3av/5/

I have updated your fiddle here. Your html tags looks more messed, but I just modified it to work for your requirement.

```
.top-category-div{
background: black;
  color: white;
        padding-bottom: 54px;
```

}

```
.container-menu{               
    margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;   
}
.category-dropdown-menu{
 margin-left: -300px;
width: 1280px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It wont work with mnargin-left because that margin will fit for your screen only, we need to capture the margin-left automatically for each different screem

Comment: You are right. Then how do you define width as 1280px always? It should be 100% right?

Comment: dude please check for min-width(1280 ) screen size I have 1280 which means my container contents will always centered and in 1280px. Which means the margin-left and right are auto, for any screen starts from 1280px will have all contents in 1280px only that helps in maintaining responsiveness.

Comment: can you check the above fiddler link which is updated?

Comment: Images are overlapped and slightly the left and right portion has gone out, I mean left and right images should equal horizontally to left side logo starting point and right side image should end at about our site review end.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsdev/p7qrv3av/8/

I have updated the left right margins as you explained. Please check again the above fiddler

Comment: But on click of any image and texts the submenu is closing how to keep submenu active

Comment: Please keep the menu active on click on images and texts only close when same categories is clicked, thank you, almost done and I will give you 50+bounty bro

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsdev/p7qrv3av/9/

    $('ul.dropdown-menu.category-dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    //The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
    // therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
    event.stopPropagation();
});

here you go buddy :-)

Comment: Yes I just got that I added slide up and slide down event for drop down and it just stays constant, thank you.

Comment: Great! Hope the bounty comes on my way

Comment: Yeah sure bro, after testing it properly I will give you only
bountys cant be gained back so if I gave you now and something went wrong in your answer then no one will answer. 
so just wait once it tested I will give you for sure thank you so much

Comment: When we stretch the browser width after loading of the page, the submenu does now take the full width. we need to refresh it again. can you help with this?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior in jsFiddler also? I don't think so, it changes the style when I opened the submenu and adjust the browser width

Comment: Please try by creating sample.html page

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your css here  Please Try This

```
.top-category-div{
    background: black;
      color: white;
          margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 54px;

}

.main-menu-div .col-sm-5, .main-menu-div .nav > li {  position: static; }
.main-menu-div .dropdown-menu { top:inherit; width:100%; }
.main-menu-div .top-category-div img { max-width:100px; }


@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .container{  
        width: 1280px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

i added these class ->

https://jsfiddle.net/shekharb/p7qrv3av/17/

```
.label{display:block; width:100%}
.top-cat-div>li{display:block}
```

to overwrite yours and removed pull-right class from sub menu.